# Should I use the BackgroundWorker class to handle a queue of tasks if I have no UI?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, backgroundworker, task-queue

I'm using .Net 3.5 (C#) and I have a queue of tasks that I want to run one after the other, I'm doing that by using the BackgroundWorker class (with it's DoWork, RunWorkerCompleted and IsBusy methodes and property).
1. Is it recommended to use the BackgroundWorker class if I don't have any UI? why?
2. I heard that the BackgroundWorker class is deprecated, is it true? does anybody know why?
3. Is there another class that can help me to do what I have mentioned above?
Thanks!

P.S.
I'm running the second task just after the first one has finished.

Comment: I would use some custom or existing threaded Job system. That might be much easier to use then a BackGroundWorker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any UI, do you need any sort of marshalling to another thread? If you're running the tasks one after another, I'd just call them directly unless you *need* to do anything more complicated. If you know you *do* need to do this in a separate thread, please post more details about your requirements (including what kind of project this is).

As far as I know, `BackgroundWorker` isn't deprecated at all. In C# 5 it will become somewhat less important due to the new async features, but it can still be used with no problems, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundWorker` class just provides an easier way to use threads. It has some relation to UI. Please see Jon Skeet's answer and his comments.. So, you can continue to use it.

> I heard that the `BackgroundWorker` class is deprecated, is it true?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx has no mention of BackgroundWorker being deprecated. **So, it is not deprecated.**

Comment: Well, it has a distinct relation to synchronization contexts - which are most commonly used with user interfaces. I don't think I've personally ever seen one *outside* the context of a user interface. Have you, out of interest?

Comment: Also, the docs introduce BackgroundWorker with: "The BackgroundWorker class allows you to run an operation on a separate, dedicated thread. Time-consuming operations like downloads and database transactions can cause your user interface (UI) to seem as though it has stopped responding while they are running. When you want a responsive UI and you are faced with long delays associated with such operations, the BackgroundWorker class provides a convenient solution." So to say it has "no relation whatsoever to UI" is an overstatement IMO.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I am not aware in what way is the backgroundworked related to synchronization context. Can you please provide any pointers

Comment: When you report progress etc, it uses the synchronization context captured when the background worker is created. That's how it manages to marshal back to the UI thread.